# Strength of the magnetic field generated by a subwoofer

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I need to ship a subwoofer via an airline company and for that the magnetic field generated by it can not exceed at a distance of 4.6 m (15 ft) from any point on the surface of the assembled consignment the value of 0.418 A/m (0.00525 gauss) or can not produces a magnetic compass deflection of 2 degrees or less.

So, the question. Is it possible to a powerful subwoofer generates a magnetic field greater than the limit specified above at the distance said?

Comment: I found this old discussion: http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/multi-way/146993-loudspeaker-magnet-aircraft-safety.html

Comment: You can try to measure with the magnetometer (electronic compass) app in your smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose the subwoofer in a ferromagnetic sheet metal case, the magnetic field of the subwoofer should be shielded. The earth's magnetic field is about 0.45G. Thus the tolerated magnetic field of about of one percent of this is extremely low.

Comment: But sheets or pieces of iron may also cause deviations of the compass.

Comment: @Pieter - That's why transport of pieces of iron might also be a problem at this airline company.